# get_object_or_404(), handler404, Http404 response. How do these things works?

Tags: python, django, backend

Could you help me with something in Django, please?
I would like to understand the sequence of execution of 404 page not found error

Let me put the code here...

url.py -----------file from django project

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500

from core import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
]

handler404 = views.error404
handler500 = views.error500
```

url.py -----------file from django app

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import index
from .views import contact
from .views import product

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('contact', contato, name='contact'),
    path('product/<int:pk>', produto, name='product'),
]
```

view.py

```
def produto(request, pk):
    print(f'PK: {pk}')
    
    prod = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
    context = {
        'product': prod
    }
    return render(request, 'product.html', context)

def error404(request, exception):
    template = loader.get_template('404.html')
    return HttpResponse(content=template.render(), content_type='text/html; charset=utf8', status=404)

def error500(request):
    template = loader.get_template('500.html')
    return HttpResponse(content=template.render(), content_type='text/html; charset=utf8', status=500)
```

I would like to understand the following:
Let's suppose that in the table 'Product' there are only 5 instances...so for the 5th instance, the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/5` ok?

Let's suppose that I try to get the 10th instance in the table that does not exist, so the line of code `prod = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)` will return the instance or return an error 404, in this case will return an error 404, ok?

So, when I enter the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/10`, this will hit the url patter `path('product/<int:pk>', produto, name='product'),` calling the view `def produto(request, pk):`
Inside that view, the instance will not be retrieved and the error 404 will be released.

So, how that error404 is sent to the url.py file for this code `handler404 = views.error404` to be executed and call the view for this error `def error404(request, exception):`?
I didn't understand how the flow of execution works...
Could someone explain it to me?

I already described the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the way to your view the request is passing all middleware layers definded on settings.MIDDLEWARE and backwards the same applies for the response. Like layers of an onion.

On the way back if the view or one of the middmeware layers raises an exception the middleware method process_exception()  is called (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) and there the 40x etc. handlers are called that in turn transform the exception into a HttpResponse with status 40x returned to the calling browser.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#exception-handling